# Is it true that $\text{Proj } R \cong \text{Proj }R^{(k)}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As in the title, I am trying to show that $\text{Proj } R \cong \text{Proj }R^{(k)}$ for $k > 0$ where $R = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} R_n$ is a graded ring and $R^{(k)} = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} R_{nk}$ is the graded ring induced from $R$. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to define the homeomorphism
$\text{Proj } R \rightarrow \text{Proj }R^{(k)}$ though I can imagine that this map should send the open set $D_+(f) \mapsto D_+(f^k)$. The natural candidate is the restriction of the associated map $i^*$ to the subset $\text{Proj } R \subseteq \text{Spec } R$ where $i : R^{(k)} \rightarrow R$ is the natural inclusion ring homomorphism. But I can't show that the image always lie in $\text{Proj } R^{(k)}$; in particular, that it doesn't contain the irrelevant ideal. Any idea or maybe counter-example?

**EDIT**: I just found out that I messed up the logic of $\text{Proj}$ i.e. $P \not\supseteq R_+$ means *"there exists $f \in R_+$ such that $f \not\in P$"*, not *"there exists $f \in P$ such that $f \not\in R_+$"*. The mentioned map does provide a homeomorphism.